# Duplicating rows in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I am looking to build a script in Google Sheets that can duplicate rows and then edit values in certain cells.

I have a webform that populates a Google Script.
Once a row is populated, I want it to duplicate itself based on how many checkboxes are ticked in the webform, and then change some of the values based on which checkboxes are checked.

Below is a mockup of a webform that sends the data to a Google Sheet.
The highlighted row in the Google Sheet represents the data from the webform, and the following 5 rows are what I am looking for the script to do.

Rows E and F have been changed based on the values from the checkboxes from the webform.

Any thought or ideas on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

[image: Webform mockup]

[image: Google Sheet mockup]

Comment: I see that there is a column named 'Variations' and according to your information the number of copies of the data is the number of values that would be in that cell.  What will trigger the code to run?  You must have code that is saving the data to the row.  You'll need to extend that code.  Your question is basically "to broad."  And you haven't included some very basic information, like where do you want the copies of the row data to go?  Will the code always be working on the last row appended to the Sheet?  Or do rows of data get overwritten?  How does your code "know" what row to set?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback... I'm aware that this is quite undefined and therefore broad. I'm not looking for the precise answer but more for pointer in the right direction to approach this.

I assume that a Google Script would run in the Sheet, and if possible it would run every time a new set of data comes in from the webform.

Regarding the placement of the rows, everything should be appended.
(E.g. a new set of data from the webform would end in row 8, and then be duplicated to row 9, 10, 11 etc.)

Comment: If the input form is in a dialog box, or sidebar created from Apps Script, then you can use `google.script.run.functionName()` to run a .gs script function.  If the input form is a Google Form, then you can trigger a function to run with an "On Form Submit" trigger.  If the input form is from something like your own website, you can trigger code to run in Apps Script with an HTTPS GET or POST request.  The first issue is getting the script to run.  You can append data with the [appendRow() method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents)